# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using enum in a class

Tags: java, enums, jetty

I am getting a weird `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` while deploying my code. No error when I compile it, but when I am deploying it using jetty, I get an error saying

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.
                                  PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'
 defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]:
  Initialization of bean failed;

nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'
  defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]:
   Invocation of init method failed;

nested exception is
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/core/model/Webhook$Event
```

The class looks like below

```
public class Webhook extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

    public enum Event {
        ORDER_CREATE,
        ORDER_UPDATE,
        ORDER_DELETE,
        TICKET_CREATE,
        TICKET_UPDATE,
        TICKET_DELETE,
        CUSTOMER_CREATE,
        CUSTOMER_UPDATE,
        CUSTOMER_DELETE,
        MENU_ITEM_UPDATE,
        CHECK_OFFER
    }

    private Event triggerEvent;

    public Event getTriggerEvent() {
        return triggerEvent;
    }

    public void setTriggerEvent(Event triggerEvent) {
        this.triggerEvent = triggerEvent;
    }

    public String getTriggerEventString() {
        return triggerEvent.toString();
    }

    public void setTriggerEventString(String triggerEvent) {
        this.triggerEvent = Event.valueOf(triggerEvent);
    }    
}
```

Any Idea whats happening? It doesn't even show what like the error is in.

Comment: It says it can't find `com/core/model/Webhook$Event`- have you checked that you're deploying that class file? (`WebHook$Event.class`)?

Comment: Won't IntellJ do it for me? Event is inside the Java class

Comment: I've no idea what IntelliJ does in terms of deployment, but you should check wherever Jetty is getting the class files.

Comment: Try to compile this file (ctrl+shift+f9 for windows, cmd+shift+f9 for mac)

Comment: which file are you talking about?

Comment: @Ritwick Webhook class file.

Answer (score 2):

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** -  Usually this indicates that we previously attempted to load a class from the classpath, but it failed
>   for some reason - now we're trying to use the class again (and thus
>   need to load it, since it failed last time), but we're not even going
>   to try to load it, because we failed loading it earlier (and
>   reasonably suspect that we would fail again). The earlier failure
>   could be a ClassNotFoundException or an ExceptionInInitializerError
>   (indicating a failure in the static initialization block) or any
>   number of other problems. The point is, a NoClassDefFoundError is not
>   necessarily a classpath problem.

When I deploy in Weblogic, I often had had NoClassDefFoundError due to Weblogic cache. May try to clean cache of jetty or rename Event enum to, for example, Event1 and try again?